# SQL Error: near line 63: near "(": syntax error

Tags: sql

When I execute this query, I get an error

> Error: near line 63: near "(": syntax error

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE  SAL > 2000 AND LEFT(ENAME,1) <> 'A'
ORDER BY HIREDATE ASC;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because of the LEFT command?

Comment: what database engine are you using?, `LEFT` doesn't exist in all of them

Comment: I'm using an online sql compiler, btw, I solved the issue by replacing the left command with  NOT  ENAME LIKE 'A%'.

Comment: Please hover your mouse over the `sql` tag you added and read what it says. You need to also provide a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax is different in some of them. Please [edit] your question to add that tag.

Comment: Your use of `LEFT` is not wrong. Try removing `ASC` since its already applied by default. And aldo cross check if all the Column names match with the table including the table name.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT(str, len)` --  returns the leftmost length characters from the string str.

```
SELECT LEFT('abcd', 3)
```

Output:    abc

Or you can replace the left with this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE  SAL > 2000 AND ENAME NOT LIKE 'A%'
ORDER BY HIREDATE ASC;
```